# Self sizing cell not working until scrolling some items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using self sizing `UITableViewCell` with some labels inside and all labels lines number is 0.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 284
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath) as! NodeCell
    let nodemodel = nodes[indexPath.row]
    cell.like.text = Utils.convert_string(string: String(nodemodel.like))
    cell.address.text = nodemodel.address
    cell.avatar.downloadedFrom(link: "www.example.com")
    cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatar.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.avatar.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(integerLiteral: 1)
    cell.avatar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.avatar.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.title.text = nodemodel.node_name
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

after running application all of my labels limited to single line and texts not showing completely until scrolling some items and then scrolling back. what is wrong? I did `layoutIfNeeded()` before returning cell but it's not working
[image]

Comment: show you constraints and code

Comment: You did not give any height constraint right?

Comment: Try calling `reloadData` inside `viewDidAppear` and remove the `layoutIfNeeded` from inside the `cellForRow`

Comment: that doesn't help @Rikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved after changing `UIStackView` distribution mode from `Fill Proportionally` to `Equal Spacing`

Comment: you can upvote the question :D that's written by me too @FaisalSyed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UITableView` `delegate` methods instead:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 284
    }
```

Comment: it's not fixing my problem

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: I'm running application on emulator with iOS 10.2